# Is it possible to test Firestore in Flask Web App locally (without deploying the website)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on small project where data is uploaded to Firestore on one page, and retrieved on another in the same website. Is it possible to test the Firestore integration when the website is hosted on localhost?

When I try accessing the Firestore functionality after deploying my website on localhost, I get:

"google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Datastore Mode projects." error.

The only documentation I can find is: "[How to deploy Flask Crud API with Firestore...](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/building-flask-api-with-cloud-firestore-and-deploying-to-cloud-run)"

Note: 
1. I looked at the error, and double checked that my project is in Firestore mode (I created the project from Firebase Console), and then used following in my Flask application to authenticate database:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

Any other inputs on this would be appreciated!

2. I tried looking into Simulators, but most of the documentation said that it's only for Cloud functions, whereas I'm trying to test simple operations.

Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. I was using cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json") code with new generated private key for authenticating my firestore database, however, system was taking an old $GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS for this purpose.

Updating that to new key fixed the issue, and yes, I am able to test FLASK app integration with Firestore on Localhost :)

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/Users/..../newkey.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that your Cloud Firestore database is in [Datastore mode instead of Native mode](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/firestore-or-datastore). Unless you never saved anything to your database, you can't change the mode.

Try creating a new project, creating a new Cloud Firestore database, and selecting Native mode:

- In the GCP console, it'll ask you to choose.
- In the Firebase console, it'll automatically select Native mode.

Comment: Thank you for responding, sorry I should have added more info. I had looked into the error and double checked that my database is in Firestore Native mode (generated through Firebase console). I used cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json") with new generated key to authenticate the app. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Found the issue and posted as an answer. Your response told me that it's possible to test Firebase on localhost, and I looked at the code again and tested few other things that solved my issue. Thank you,